# Adding a 'juice collection' section on a cutting board

Tags: router, cutting-board

I have a core box bit and I would like to add a trench if you will around the cutting board abot 3/4" in. I do not think you can do it with a router table and i know it has to be done with the hand router. How should I do it? The best I could think of was having a frame around it but there bit would be much to far in, and if I did make it bigger then I only risk the cutting board going flying in some direction and hitting the frame. I could just do it and then cut the wood but I do not want to waste the wood like that. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't already have one, get a 'router guide bushing' that suits your router. (You might have to replace the base plate to find a bushing that fits.) The only sizing requirement is that the interior of the bushing is bigger than your core bit.

You'll want a rectangular chunk of something to sit in the middle of the cutting board. Size it to give you the cutting path you want. (It can be any material -- it just needs smooth edges.) Hot glue or double-sided tape the guide to the cutting board.

Take progressively deeper cuts -- just a little at a time. The only hard part will be turning around the corners cleanly. Hold on tight and it'll go fine. If you nipped a 45 degree off the corners, it'd be a touch easier.

Comment: I think I will be doing a rectangular chunk of wood. I can not believe I did not think of that. Thank you! And I will look for a router guide.

Comment: A couple of tips: My parents had one a _long_ time ago - the groove curved around the corners instead of being square, it was shallower at one end than the other to encourage everything to flow, and the groove died into the handle area so it was easy to pour out. If your board is deep enough, you could route an indentation for a bowl/container to fit under the handle as a dripping catcher to make clean up easier (to be honest, I think they just put the handle over the edge of the sink).